# How to get sysdate with different formats?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get sysdate in following format in SQL Server?

> 1/1/2014
>
> 1/2/2014
>
> 1/3/2014

i.e **`M/D/YYYY`**

I searched in google, i got different formats, but i want following format. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check with my answer

Comment: Please check my answer too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the CONVERT documentation in msdn article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

You can see many formats here.
For your case use

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),yourdate,101) as formatteddate
```

Based on your question edit I would recommend `datepart` and associated functions like `MONTH, DAY, YEAR`

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'+CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Another edit for 2 years back

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(yy,-2,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'+CAST(DAY(DATEADD(yy,-2,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'+CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(yy,-2,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Comment: @DhruvJoshi gud..!! :)

Comment: please say one thing. How to go to 2 years back with your query..I.e.1/1/2012
1/2/2012
1/3/2012

Comment: @user3269598 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14535 check the fiddle i have edited his query for you..!!

Comment: @user3269598 Can you check my answer in the name of Vignesh Kumar

Comment: @user3269598 Any more scenarios ?

Comment: No,Thank you DhruvJoshi

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [M/D/YYYY]
```

Comment: It is giving 02/04/2014, But i want like this 2/4/2014. Thanks

Comment: @user3269598 i have updated my answer can you check with that

Comment: Your second query is returning the same value as first query

Comment: Your second query just uses a different alias, it does not change the output format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT ( GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US' ) AS DateConvert;
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14518)

[image]

```
SELECT FORMAT ( GETDATE(), 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US' ) AS DateConvert;
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14519)

[image]

Updated my code as you needed before two years

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'+CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())- 2 AS VARCHAR(4))
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29406)**

[image]

To know more [Click here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/21/sql-server-display-datetime-in-specific-format-sql-in-sixty-seconds-033-video/)

[FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

## Updated answer

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())))+'/'+LTRIM(STR(DAY(GETDATE())))+'/'+STR(YEAR(GETDATE()),4)
```

## [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29408)

[image]

## Alternate Way

```
DECLARE @dt datetime
SET @dt= GETDATE()
SELECT LTRIM(STR(MONTH(@dt)))+'/'+LTRIM(STR(DAY(@dt)))+'/'+STR(YEAR(@dt),4)
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29411)

[image]

```
 SELECT STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(CHAR(10),@SomeExampleDate,101),'/0','/'),1,1,'')
```

## [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29412)

Comment: wat sql server are you using?? have you checked the fiddle??